# Dúvida sobre banco de dados de aplicação feita em C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Estou criando uma aplicação em C#, porém me veio uma dúvida. Qual banco de dados é utilizado para que não seja necessário instalar a base de dados no sistema do cliente? Por exemplo: Se eu fosse utilizar o Postgresql como eu poderia integrar a aplicação com o banco de dados na hora de instalar sem precisar instalar o próprio SGBD? Não que o SGBD seja o Postgresql, seria algo tipo SQL Server que já vem incluído na própria biblioteca do C# ou SQLite algo do tipo?

Comment: @IsraelSouza, você não precisa instalar o BD, desde q seu web.config ou app.config aponte para um endereço IP do BD. Agora, mesmo q instale se faz necessário apontar conforme foi falado.

Answer (score 0):

O recomendado pela Microsoft é o [SQL Server Express LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx). Ele embarca em um único arquivo de dados uma instância do SQL Server, não demandando instalação de um banco de dados apenas para a aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLite` seria uma ótima opção, além de o banco ser **Cross Platform**, é BEM leve e você só precisa importar os `runtimes` pro `C#`. Já existe um db manager pra ele ([SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/)). Já pensou usar o mesmo DB no Android?

- https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki
- http://www.macoratti.net/10/03/c_sqlt1.htm